# Android : How to give dynamic values to custom components in android

Tags: android, custom-controls, custom-component

Hi I have a custom component in my XML and it has  static values for textHeader,textValue,textStatsCount,textStatsColor

this is the xml code

```
<com.my.androproject.customWidget.Textdesigner
    android:layout_width="122sp"
    android:layout_height="56sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25sp"
    androproject:textHeader="Operations"
    androproject:textValue="28" 
    androproject:textStatsCount="+20"
    androproject:textStatsPercent="+40%"
    androproject:textStatsColor="#00FF00" />
```

In the Textdesigner class

```
public class Textdesigner extends RelativeLayout {
    // this constructor call will used when instantiating the object manually (not from a layout XML file).
    public Textdesigner (Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    // this from xml layout
    public Textdesigner (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

- I want to set the values for textHeader,textValue,textStatsCount,textStatsColor from java code(dynamically). I dont know how to do that??? Please help me..
- I want to create a new component by using the custom component class Textdesigner ..

can any one help me how to do that in java code... any link or tutorial for learning custom components will be great.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

you must have been adding textHeader, and other component in layout text designer, set these attibutes threre on the components you are adding.

Comment: I have a separate method like

Comment: public void setTextOne(String text) {
  textheader.setText(text);
 }

Comment: but  i dont know which context file i have to pass in object instantiation of my textdesigner class(for constructor) and how to call setTextOne method???